# Unicode characters in Julia: star symbol

Tags: unicode, julia

I am trying to simplify the notation in a couple of functions using some unicode characters. In one of this function I have tried to use the star symbol (\star) but I've got several errors and warnings.

Please have a look at the following working example:

```
a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
```

- Gives: a 3×3 Array{Int64,2}

```
a⋆ = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
```

- Gives: ERROR: syntax: unexpected "="

Why the star symbol is not working when it is used as above? Does it have a designed functionality in Julia?

Comment: What does Julia's section on valid identifier characters tell you?

Comment: That is not clear to me. I had a look at that section before. First, it says: "The only explicitly disallowed names for variables are the names of built-in statements". With regards to unicode sm characters - as the star symbol - it says that they "are also valid identifiers, but are parsed specially. In some contexts, operators can be used just like variables". It is not clear to me whether the star symbol is used only for user defined methods or not.

Comment: That's what [I found too](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/variables/#allowed-variable-names), when I went looking (I'd never heard of Julia before). Sounds more complicated (in this regard) than the typical programming language... I wanted to see what Unicode categories U+22C6 (⋆) is in, but sadly [the page for it](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=22C6) on unicode.org is down (it's not clear to me whether that's permanent or temporary). But the code charts say it's a math symbol, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `⋆` symbol parses as an infix operator:

```
julia> dump(parse("a⋆b"))
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((3,))
    1: Symbol ⋆
    2: Symbol a
    3: Symbol b
  typ: Any
```

A case could be made for allowing `⋆` as a character in identifier names, but that would be a breaking change and so far we have generally parsed characters that are generally considered to be operator-like in the Unicode standard as operators with the appropriate precedence.

Comment: Thank you @StefanKarpinski, this is what I wanted to know. I think there is no need to create an exception. Maybe giving more flexibility for subscripts or superscripts would be nice and may remove the advantage of using the *star* symbol or similar. I don't know, however, how difficult and/or valuable it may be in general.

Comment: Subscript Unicode can be used in identifiers e.g. `v₁ = 10.0`, but there is no keyboard shortcut (maybe this cut be remedied (maybe \1). Copy-paste to the REPL worked for me.